# The current URL, , didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have already checked this error on other stackoverflow threads but don't find any error on my code. Perhaps I'm tired but it seems ok to me.

website.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
#from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Register and Login
    url(r'^inscription\.html$', 'membres.views.register'),

    # List of users
    url(r'^membres', include('membres.urls')),
)
```

membres.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('membres.views',
    url(r'^/(?P<slug>\d+)\.html$', 'view_user_public')
)
```

Of course I get :

```
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^inscription\.html$
^membres ^/(?P<slug>\d+)\.html$

The current URL, membres/nicolas.html, didn't match any of these.
```

The inscription.html works properly. In the `membres.urls.py` file, if I change `r'^/(?P<slug>\d+)\.html$` to `r'^\.html$`, the url `membres.html` works properly and loads the view...

What's wrong with `r'^/(?P<slug>\d+)\.html$` ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try removing the `^` at the start of the url. That means "start of the string", which it won't match (because the string starts with `membres`.

Comment: Why are you ending every URL with `.html`? There's no need for that.

Comment: Because that's how I find a URL pretty :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\d+` would match digits only. `nicolas` is not composed of digits.

`\w+` is what you're looking for.

More generally, `[\w-]+` for slugs which typically contain hyphens.